# Google ad manager API report downloader says written to /tmp but not visible in databricks DBFS

Tags: python, databricks, google-ad-manager

I am trying to retrieve a Google Ad Manager report (visible in the UI), from the API via Databricks.

Google and Github documentation [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/ad_manager/v202108/report_service/run_saved_query.py) has the following code:

```py
report_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.csv.gz', delete=False)

# Download report data.
report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(
    report_job_id, export_format, report_file)

report_file.close()

# Display results.
print('Report job with id "%s" downloaded to:\n%s' %
      (report_job_id, report_file.name))
```

Which returns:

```
Report job with id "12524715816" downloaded to: /tmp/tmp7lh2ssj8.csv.gz
```

However, this file is not present in databricks DBFS /tmp (or anywhere I can see)

Can someone point me in the right direction?
I tried changing report_file to an explicit path in the DBFS but gives error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'.
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `DownloadReportToFile` expects a file-like object, you can't pass a filepath which is a string. That's the reason for `AttributeError`.
Instead of `tempfile`, have you tried with a normal file? `report_file = open('/some/path/myfile.csv.gz', 'w')`

Comment: Thank you Shiva, that makes sense. Do you think the above example is actually writing a file somewhere?